# The meaning of "classical distribution solution" for a differential inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading this [paper](http://www.dmi.unipg.it/~pucci/lavori/grado.pdf) and in page 12 Lemma.3.3, they say that $w$ is a "classical distribution solution" of the differential inequality (3.3). Can anyone please explain me what this mean?

Edit: I think that the correct definition: $$\int_0^T\operatorname{sgn}(w(t))q(t)\Phi(w'(t))\phi'(t)\geq 0,\ \forall\ \phi\in C_0^\infty(0,T),\ \phi\geq 0 $$

Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From page 3 of the same paper, lines 8-9.

> By a classical solution (or a classical distribution solution) of (1.1) or (1.2) in $\Omega$ we mean a non–negative function $u \in C^1(\Omega)$ which satisﬁes (1.1) or (1.2) in the distribution sense.

This seems inconsistent with Lemma 3.3, where nonnegativity of $w$ is not assumed.

In any case, for functions of one variable, saying "$(\dots)'\ge 0$ in the sense of distributions" is a fancy way of saying that $(\dots)$ is a non-decreasing function. Thus, assumption (3.3) says that $q(t)\Phi(w'(t))$ is nondecreasing when $w\ge 0$, and non-increasing when $w\le 0$. It is then proved that only the first alternative holds.

Comment: So, my definition is wrong? and what happens with the additional term "sgn"?

Comment: @Tomás It's incomplete: $w\in C^1$ is a part of the concept. Also, integration by part brings a minus sign, which you did not account for. And when $w$ changes sign, integration by parts becomes questionable: one may be worried about picking up a $\delta$ function. So, I would not say it's wrong but you should carefully consider it. // In particular, I would write the inequality (3.3) as two inequalities: $\ge 0$ in the domain where $w>0$ (which is an open set), and $\le 0$ in the domain where $w<0$. Then you get a weak formulation with $\phi$  supported within one of two domains.

Comment: I'm really confused. Please take a look in the beginning of the proof, He says: (multiplying (3.3) by $w$ and integrating). Why can he do this?

Comment: @Tomás Read carefully: the test function is the restriction of $w$ to the interval $(t_0,t_1)$ where $w<0$. In this interval our equation says $(q\Phi(w')),\le 0$, since the sign of $w$ is negative. Since $w$ is a negative test function, we get $\le 0$  after integration by parts.

Comment: So you are saying me that in the interval $(t_0,t_1)$, we have that $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}q(t)\Phi(w'(t))\phi'(t)\leq 0,\ \forall\ \phi\in C_0^\infty(t_0,t_1),\ \phi\geq 0 $$ and then he takes $\phi=w$?

Comment: @Tomás Again, watch the signs. We have $$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}q(t)\Phi(w'(t))\phi'(t)\geq 0,\ \forall\ \phi\in C_0^\infty(t_0,t_1),\ \phi\geq 0$$ and then take $\phi=-w$.

Comment: Please @5pm take a look in the end of the proof. He says: "By integration of (3.3) on $(t_1,t)$". How can he do this? If $w\geq 0$ then, we have that for all $\phi\geq 0$, $\phi\in C_0^\infty(0,T)$ $$\int_0^T q(t)\Phi(w'(t))\phi'(t)\leq 0$$. Is that true? Is that the meaning of (3.3)? If is, how can he deduce from it the integration by parts? I mean: $q$ and $\Phi$ are a priori not differentiabe functions, so the symbol $(q\Phi)'$ is nonsense if it is taked formally. I'm really confused here.

Comment: Now, I'm starting to believe, ($w\geq 0$) that the really meaning of (3.3) is: for every non-negative function $\phi\in C^\infty(0,T)$ we have that $$\int_0^T q(t)\Phi(w'(t))\phi'(t)\leq q(T)\Phi(w'(T))\phi(T)-q(0)\Phi(w'(0))\phi(0)$$ Does it makes sense?

Comment: @Tomás Every distribution is differentiable in the sense of distributions, and integration by parts works by design. I already gave my explanation of the meaning of (3.3) in my answer. You can compare it with your interpretations.